# First/Last page buttons in Laravel 5 pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel's default pagination (BootstrapThreePresenter). I'm happy with how it works, however I'd like to also display **first page** and **last page** buttons.

Do I need to create a custom presenter for this? Or is there an easy way to configure the default one, so it uses those two buttons?

Comment: It looks like you will need to create a custom presenter.  I found this question which might help you, though it's starting with something besides BootstrapThreePresenter.  Hopefully it will get you on the right track.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567741/laravel-4-custom-pagination-go-to-first-last-page-and-show-a-fixed-number-of-li