# Laravel 5 Simple Pagination Text Render

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5 Simple Pagination showing arrows instead of 'next' and 'previous' text. Any way to edit this?

```
«
»
```

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567741/laravel-4-custom-pagination-go-to-first-last-page-and-show-a-fixed-number-of-li

Comment: Can you add in the code for your controller that generates the pagination?